# Toshiba Satellite C55D-A5392 won't boot install or try Ubuntu

Tags: installation, laptop, toshiba-satellite, toshiba

Downloaded 64 bit ISO for 13.10.

Whether burned to DVD or on bootable USB it's the same result.

The laptop boots to the GRUB try/install/oem/check menu.

When `try` or `install` is chosen the screen changes to the Ubuntu logo with the animated dots below it and then animates for a while. After that the screen goes blank  and stays that way. Attempts to bring up console with alt-f1 don't work.

Modified boot options and removed `splash` and `quiet`, watching the boot process I see nothing unusual, until the system apparently starts X and the screen goes and stays blank.

I ran check on the USB stick and it says the Ubuntu system on there checks out.

I've tried turning off UEFI boot, but then neither USB nor DVD boot at all. Secure boot is off (has been the whole time).

So far I'm stuck booting into Windows 8.1 or not at all it seems. Right now it feels like my options are to use Ubuntu from VirtualBox within Windows or just return the computer.

Any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix pointed to by possible duplicates:

At GRUB screen, up/down arrow to select `install` option.

Press `e` key to edit boot options.

Remove `splash` and `quiet`. Add `nomodeset`.

Installer now runs as expected.